# Mac terminal prompt's machine name becomes "bogon" after using traceroute

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I was doing some traceroute test yesterday, and today, my Mac terminal's user prompt becomes

```
`bogon:~ myUserName$`
```

Also when I'm doing traceroute like:

```
traceroute www.google.com
```

it stops with this log:

```
bogon (192.168.0.1)  1.158 ms  0.908 ms  0.746 ms
```

`192.168.0.1` is the address of my wireless router.
I still can surf the internet though.

Comment: how long do you have it running ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I'm not sure.

Comment: well I just did it, and after 3 min or so and 13 steps it stops, but it does not changes my computer ID

Comment: @Dwayne bogon is your (bogus?) machine name and not your user name.

Comment: @klanomath you are right, this part is machine name, and I have never changed my machine name. Also it is bogon, may be it means bog on?

Answer (score 3):

By some searching I found a **solution** to this problem.

First, change the *DNS address* in your network configurations to a better one, like google's 8.8.8.8.
Second, run `sudo hostname theMachineNameYouWant` in terminal.

The **reason** for this:

They say that when you are doing DNS lookup/reverse lookup, the DNS server can give your machine a host name, this function should be turned off for public DNS servers, but I don't know why the DNS server of my local ISP has it on.

Since my machine uses a router, so it has a IP like 192.168.0.x in LAN, I don't know why but when using *traceroute*, this IP will be sent to the DNS server for a reverse lookup, and since it is a reserved IP address, the DNS server returns a hostname as *bogon*, thus, changes my machine's hostname.

So what is bogon? Bogon means the type of IP addresses that should not appear in a traceroute, like a reserved IP address.

[bogon on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogon_filtering).

Comment: I'd recommend changing the DNS settings _on your router_ to use something other than your ISP's DNS servers. They are running some mis-configured DNS and who knows what that means they're doing with DNS. Bad ISP, bad.